# Type Error: conditional type Exclude not working on Generic type

Tags: typescript

In the following code when AllKeys correctly resolve to "name" | "dob" | "age", however when I exclude "age" using Exclude conditional type, SomeKeys resolves to nothing, though I would expect it to resolve to "name" | "dob".

```
declare type RequiredProps = {
   name: any,
   dob: any, 
   age: any,
}
declare type AllKeys<T extends RequiredProps> = keyof T;
declare type SomeKeys<T extends RequiredProps> = Exclude<keyof T, "age">;
function Test<C extends RequiredProps>() {
    const props1: AllKeys<C> = "name";
    const props2: SomeKeys<C> = "name"; //Error: Type '"name"' is not assignable to type 'Exclude<keyof C, "age">'
}
```

Comment: I think the compiler is not clever enough to handle generics and conditional types the way you want.  I'd change the definition of `SomeKeys` to something like `declare type SomeKeys<T extends RequiredProps> = Exclude<keyof RequiredProps | keyof T, "age">;` which should end up the same when a concrete `T` is specified, but the compiler can at least tell that `"name"` is assignable to it.

Comment: Yeah, Seems like a bug in the typescript compiler. I will open a bug report. Nice workaround though. thanks.